# AJAX call won't work on production, but works local

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've got a very strange situation.

I'm using an AJAX call to pass some parameters to my code-behind and everything works fine on local, but on my production environment I'm not being able to recover the parameter values in code-behind.

I've added here a few breakpoints just to you show where the problem is. The first one captures some parameter values just to check if they are empty/null (it's not actually part of the code) and the second will return an error if "inscricao" is null (which should not be).

[image]

When running the app in my local environment, I'm able to get the parameter values without any problems, as shown here.

[image]

But the same app, accessing the same database, with the same values will enter the second breakpoint and return a message as such, on production.

[image]

I have other AJAX post methods in the same page that work just fine, and as I said, it works fine on local. Is there any way to find out why the same code doesn't run on production? The other AJAX methods I have on the same page also work on production, this is the only exception.

I'll add the AJAX code below:

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    url: '?handler=SolicitarSafe2Pay',
                    datatype: "application/json",
                    data: {
                        valor: valortotal,
                        IDInscricao: Number(inscricaoID),
                        HtmlResumo: resumoemail,
                        IDCupom: idUsoUnico,
                        Nome: $Nome.val(),
                        NomeSocial: $NomeSocial.val(),
                        CPF: $CPF.val(),
                        Telefone: $Telefone.val(),
                        CEP: $CEP.val(),
                        Pais: $Pais.val(),
                        Estado: $Estado.val(),
                        Cidade: $Cidade.val(),
                        Endereco: $Endereco.val(),
                        Numero: $Numero.val(),
                        Bairro: $Bairro.val(),
                        Complemento: $Complemento.val(),
                        FormaPagamento: Number($FormaPagamento.val()),
                        NomeCartao: $NomeCartao.val(),
                        NumeroCartao: $NumeroCartao.val(),
                        CVV: $CVV.val(),
                        Vencimento: $Vencimento.val(),
                        Parcelas: Number($Parcelas.val())
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        ...
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr);  // to see the error message
                    }
                });
```

I've tried adding the RequestVerificationToken as a header, directly on the data object and even decorate the page with [IgnoreAntiForgeryToken]. All these options work on my local machine, but the same error still occurs on production.

Comment: Do you mean you will get the error after you use ajax to call the handler?What error you will get ifor the request in Network?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX will call the handler as expected, but every parameter is null on my production environment and the all have assigned values on the local machine we run tests.